# Maximum weight path with restricted weights

Tags: algorithm

We know that finding a maximum weight path between two vertices is np-hard. But if we restrict edge weights, for eg. all edge weights are less than some particular value x. I am defining problem below clearly.

I have a directed graph G(V,E) in which weight of every edge is between 1 and |V|. I want to find maximum weight path between the two vertices u and v.

Is this problem polynomial-time solvable?

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid your restricted problem is still NP-hard because finding the longest simple path is NP-complete even if the weights are all equal to 1.

A proof is on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem#NP-hardness):

> The NP-hardness of the unweighted longest path problem can be shown using a reduction from the Hamiltonian path problem: a graph G has a Hamiltonian path if and only if its longest path has length n − 1, where n is the number of vertices in G. Because the Hamiltonian path problem is NP-complete, this reduction shows that the decision version of the longest path problem is also NP-complete. In this decision problem, the input is a graph G and a number k; the desired output is "yes" if G contains a path of k or more edges, and no otherwise.[1]
>
> If the longest path problem could be solved in polynomial time, it could be used to solve this decision problem, by finding a longest path and then comparing its length to the number k. Therefore, the longest path problem is NP-hard. The question "does there exist a simple path in a given graph with at least k edges" is NP-complete.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Suppose if we know a priori that there are no positive weight cycles in the graph and no restrictions on edge weights, then is it solvable? I think we can use the bellman-ford algorithm. right?